# Session Timeout too frequently even after setting 60 minutes in web config

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have hosted my asp.net web application on IIS. I have set session timeout as 60 minutes in 'Web.config'.
Also in pool>advanced settings>idle-timeout as 60 minutes but still my session is expiring with 2 minutes without any error on the pages and too may users are facing the same issue with in some specific time pattern.

Comment: Did you enable form authentication on IIS? If you enable it, timeout is also need to be set .

Comment: I have used '28800' in minutes as timeout for form authentication. but the thing is we are facing this issue more on Friday and there is no activities are scheduled on the server on Friday.

Comment: What do you mean "face this issue more on Friday"? If the session is lost due to no activities, it is because the application pool is idle for too long to trigger the application pool recycling.

Comment: Application is not ideal at that time. user logged in n performing some activity and suddenly session getting timed out and that period of time all users who are accessing the portal is facing the same issue. 
For example if user logged in at10:30 am then session will expire on 10:33 am 
then again after login at10:33 am session will work fine for 30 min or more. and again cycles repeat. Frequency is more on Friday.

This pattern is for all users who are facing this issue . Time mentioned on above is just for example.